# HTTP Cookie Request Header sequence of events

Tags: http, cookies, session-cookies, jsessionid

I am a little uncertain about the sequence of events when using cookies. Here's what I think happens if a client application repeatedly requests the same page from the server:

1. client application makes a request
2. server side returns with a Set-Cookie response header
3. client makes another request, putting the cookie returned in step 2 in to the HTTP request "Cookie" header
4. server side returns but with no Set-Cookie in the response header

Is that the correct sequence? ( I'm particularly interested in Step 4 - does the server return a Set-Cookie in response to a request that has supplied a cookie )

The cookie in question is actually a JSESSIONID cookie, if that makes any difference.

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the correct sequence. However, I've seen many applications sending back "Set-Cookie" header with the same value. It does not harm the flow, since values are the same and even if client updates the cookie it's still the same value (thus, the same session).

Comment: Thanks Piotrek - what I'm finding is that my web/application server is "sometimes" sending the Set-Cookie at step 4, but is altering the value that I pass in at others. If a pass in "cook123_node01" I sometimes get no Set-Cookie, but sometimes get Set-Cookie "cook123_node02" - ie, the same prefix to the cookie, but a different suffix. The suffix is used for routing the traffic to nodes within a JBOSS cluster, so when that value changes, our session affinity also becomes broken. I'm thinking this is a server misconfiguration, but wanted a bit of confirmation before I kick up a stink.

Comment: You're welcome ;) Usually new Set-Cookie header is set in two cases: previous session has expired (timeout) or user has been authenticated successfully (in order to prevent session fixation)